# vue components not rendering in IE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs

I create Vue.js components and they works just fine in Edge, Chrome, Firefox etc, but not rendering in IE11.
I use gulp to build a project and Babel to compile es6 to es5.

.babelrc

```
{
 "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"],
  "presets": [
    ["vue", {"eventModifiers": false}],
    ["@babel/preset-env",{"useBuiltIns": "entry"}]]
}
```

May be i need others presets ?

Answer (score 0):

The @babel/present-env preset works in such a way that you need to define which browsers the build script should support.

You could create a browserlist that contains the exact browsers or browser support percentages you want to support - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targets

For Modern browsers + IE11 (since the support is somewhere above 2%), you could use:

```
{
  "browserslist": [
    "> 2%"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as IE11 doesn't support IE11 you have to edit your

> babelrc (Babel 7)

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@vue/app",
      {
        "targets": {
          "ie": "11"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

let me know if that helps. If you are using Babel 6 then check Alen Genzić response.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it did not help.
I added @vue/app:

yarn add @ vue / babel-preset-app --dev

and changed the .babelrc file:

{
   "presets": [
     [
       "@ vue / app",
       {
         "targets": {
           "ie": "11"
         }
       }
     ],
     ["@ babel / preset-env", {"useBuiltIns": "entry"}]]
}

Problem still exists.

Comment: It's my package.json file: 

{
....
  "devDependencies": {
    ....
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^3.5.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-vue": "^2.0.2",
   ...
  }
....
}